How can I deel with gcc compile error in vscode cause by path separator?
When I run compile C source file task with gcc in vscode, the command "gcc -g ${workspaceFolder}/src/main.c" will be like "gcc -g D:\xx/src\main.c" , and the finnal error tips is "D:xx/src/main.c No such file or directory", so how can I set the path separator type to backward slash "/" in vscode.
I tried to find "Path Separaotrs" and "Slash", but it doesn't work. I can't find the solution from Google.
